# appengine - can't find my domain setup

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm maintaining a app that is hosted in GAE (appengine), 
The app is set up to work with custom domain builder.go-arc.com
(I didn't do the set up - it was done before I got the project).

but when I go to my app in https://appengine.google.com/settings or in https://console.developers.google.com/project/go-arc-builder/appengine/settings/domains/add?authuser=1
I don't see the domain listed under Domain Setup and 
Custom domains

My question is: how/where do I configure my domain?

The reason I need this is to configure SSL for the domain.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, custom domains and SSL are set up in different places (for now).

Custom domains ARE configured int the Developer console in the **appengine/settings/domains** section.

In order to set SSL you need to link you GAE application to a Google Apps Domain and then add the SSL in the **Security > SSL for custom domains**

Check: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl